# Inject Koin in Java classes

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service-locator, koin

I'm trying to replace Dagger 2 to [Koin](https://insert-koin.io) in my current project and I don't want to rewrite some classes in Kotlin to use it.

Is possible to inject with Koin in java classes?

In Kotlin is just

```
// Inject MyPresenter
val presenter : MyPresenter by inject()
```

Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is possible. Both Java and Kotlin run on the JVM and thus should be interoperable.

Comment: Yeah, they work. But I would like to know how can I access inject using Koin framework.

Comment: This might help you...https://github.com/Ekito/koin/issues/81

Comment: Excellent, @keshavAggarwal

This is what I need
https://gist.github.com/fredy-mederos/b74e8c2f2ca2f0f5d5910bcb694cbdbf

Comment: Hey, Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 25):

Yes it is Possible.
Just sync project with this gradle file

```
implementation "org.koin:koin-java:$koin_version"
```

In your java class replace

```
// Inject MyPresenter
private val presenter : MyPresenter by inject()
```

with

```
private Lazy<MyPresenter> presenter = inject(MyPresenter.class);
```

and get presenter method inside Java class like

```
presenter.getValue().sayHello()
```

Comment: Hey @pawan soni, could you clarify which imports you are using for inject and Lazy? is it
`import static org.koin.core.KoinComponentKt.inject;`
and 
`import kotlin.Lazy;`
?

Comment: kotlin.Lazy  and org.koin.java.KoinJavaComponent.inject

Comment: Per Koin's GitHub page: `// Koin for Java developers is now part of core` so no need to add any extra implementations in the grade file.

Answer (score 13):

You no longer need the additional `koin-java` dependency as this is now a part of `koin-android` & `koin-core`.

```java
// Imports
import static org.koin.java.KoinJavaComponent.get;
import static org.koin.java.KoinJavaComponent.inject;
import static org.koin.core.qualifier.QualifierKt.named;
import static org.koin.core.parameter.DefinitionParametersKt.parametersOf;

// Lazy injection
Lazy<MyDependency> dependency = inject(MyDependency.class);

// Eager injection
MyDependency dependency = get(MyDependency.class);

// Named injection
get(MyDependency.class, named("MyNamedDependency"));

// Parameter injection
get(MyDependency.class, null, () -> parametersOf(this));
```

[Koin Android Java docs](https://insert-koin.io/docs/quickstart/android-java/)

Comment: Hi, I was trying to implement .get() but got Not enough information to infer type variable T error.

Comment: The doc page is not working (anymore)

Answer (score 2):

A class or file can either have .kt extension means Kotlin, or have .java extension means Java. You can't write a file or class in both the languages simultaneously.

But your Java and Kotlin files can talk with each other, i.e you can a Java class with a variable and access that variable in your Kotlin file or vice-versa.

So you can inject a Kotlin class reference and use that in your Java class and Vice-versa.

This might help: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html

I hope that clears the doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
// Java Compatibility
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android-compat:$koin_version"
```

Instead

```
implementation "org.koin:koin-java:$koin_version"
```

Don't forget

```
// Add Maven Central to your repositories if needed
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Importante point

> Due to Jcenter shutdown, the koin project's maven group id was
> previously org.koin and is now io.insert-koin. Please check your
> configuration with modules below.

See official documentation [here](https://insert-koin.io/docs/setup/v3)

Have a good job!

Answer (score 0):

It is, make sure you import in gradle the koin for java library and use above answers.

Gradle:

```
implementation "org.koin:koin-java:2.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

following code worked for me **without** org.koin:koin-java:$koin_version dependency:

```
private MyPresenter presenter = org.koin.java.KoinJavaComponentKoinJavaComponent.inject(MyPresenter.class).getValue();
```